# Asignar posicion consecutivo a un registro en MySql PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola tengo una tabla donde tengo muchos registros y una de sus columnas se llama orden.

Donde me piden que cuando agrego un registro nuevo, este se coloque justo debajo de donde le hice click agregar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa tabla es generada por un foreach en PHP.

```
    <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM lineas_carac WHERE bloque='$cosa->bloque' AND lineas_carac_seccion='$seccion' AND ano='$ano' ORDER BY orden ASC";
      $bloqueFoco = $cosa->bloque;
      $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);
      $resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $resultadojson = json_encode($resultado);
      $obj = json_decode($resultadojson);
      //echo $query . "<br>";
      foreach ($obj as $cosa) {
      }

    ?>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg b" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mostrasLineas<?php echo $colapseLinea; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Mostrar Líneas</button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="mostrasLineas<?php echo $colapseLinea; ?>">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <form action="lineas_ver.php#<?php echo $bloqueFoco; ?>" method="post">

          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>


              <th id="Estaca">Estaca</th>
              <th>Línea de Cruzamiento</th>
              <th>Selección</th>
              <th>AO</th>
              <th>RC</th>
              <th>Semillas Plantadas</th>
              <th>Nacidos</th>
              <th class="celdaGerminacion">G%</th>
              <th>PA. F</th>
              <th>I%</th>
              <th>Gen. Fillial</th>
              <th>Cruzamiento</th>
              <th>Vegetativo</th>
              <th>Reproductivo</th>
              <th>Laboratorio</th>
              <th>Observaciones</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>

            </thead>

            <tbody>



              <?php foreach ($obj as $cosa) { ?>



                <form method="post" action="lineas_ver.php#<?php echo $bloqueFoco; ?>">

                  <input type="hidden" name="anoMoverLinea" value="<?php echo $ano; ?>" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="lineas_carac_id" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_id; ?>" />

                  <input type=hidden min='1900-01-01' max='9999-12-31' class="form-control" name="fecha_siembra" value="<?php echo $fecha_siembra_bloque; ?>">

                  <input type="hidden" name="lineas_carac_seccion" value="<?php echo $lineas_carac_seccion; ?>" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="bloqueDel" value="<?php echo $bloque_linea; ?>" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="ano" value="<?php echo $cosa->ano; ?>" />

                  <input type="hidden" name="anoActualizar" value="<?php echo $filtro_bloque_ano; ?>" />




                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_estaca" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_estaca; ?>"></td>

                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="linea_num" value="<?php echo $cosa->linea_num; ?>"></td>


                    <td>
                      <?php $seleccion = $cosa->lineas_carac_seleccion; ?>
                      <input type='text' class='form-control' name="lineas_carac_seleccion" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_seleccion; ?>">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <input type='text' class='form-control' name="lineas_carac_ao" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_ao; ?>">

                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <input type='text' class='form-control' name="lineas_carac_rc" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_rc; ?>">

                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_numsemilla" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_numsemilla; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_germinacion" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_germinacion; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td class="celdaGerminacion">

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_porcentaje_germinacion" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_porcentaje_germinacion; ?>" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_paf" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_paf; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_i" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_i; ?>" readonly>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_generacion" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_generacion; ?>">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <a href="<?php echo 'cruzamientos_linea_ver.php?lineas_id=' . $cosa->linea_num; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Ver</button></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <a href="<?php echo 'lineas_vegetativo.php?lineas_id=' . $cosa->linea_num . '&bloque=' . $bloque_linea . '&seleccion=' . $seleccion . '&id_linea_carac=' . $cosa->lineas_carac_id; ?> "><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cargar</button></a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <a href="<?php echo 'lineas_reproductiva.php?lineas_id=' . $cosa->linea_num . '&bloque=' . $bloque_linea . '&seleccion=' . $seleccion . '&id_linea_carac=' . $cosa->lineas_carac_id; ?> "><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cargar</button></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="<?php echo 'lineas_laboratorio.php?lineas_id=' . $cosa->linea_num . '&bloque=' . $bloque_linea . '&seleccion=' . $seleccion . '&id_linea_carac=' . $cosa->lineas_carac_id; ?> "><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cargar</button></a>
                    </td>

                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lineas_carac_observaciones" value="<?php echo $cosa->lineas_carac_observaciones; ?>">
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <button type="submit" name="actualizarLinea" value="actualizarLinea" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="submit" id="moverLinea" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          Mover
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="moverLinea">
                          <?php
                          //SELECT PARA MOVER
                          $query = "SELECT bloque, seccion FROM linea_bloque";
                          $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                          $resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                          $resultadojson = json_encode($resultado);
                          $obj = json_decode($resultadojson);
                          $seleccionNro = 0;
                          foreach ($obj as $cosa2) {  ?>




                            <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" name="moverLinea" value="<?php echo $cosa2->bloque . '.' . $cosa2->seccion; ?>"><?php echo $cosa2->bloque; ?></button>







                          <?php }  ?>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="orden" value="<?php echo $cosa->orden; ?>">
                    <td><button type="submit" name="subir_linea" value="subir_linea"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i></button></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="arriba" value="1">


                    <td><button type="submit" name="bajar_linea" value="bajar_linea"><i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i></button></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="abajo" value="1">
                </form>
                <td>
                  <a href="<?php echo 'linea_del.php?lineas_id=' . $cosa->linea_num . '&bloque=' . $bloque_linea . '&anoDel=' . $ano . '&id_linea_carac=' . $cosa->lineas_carac_id; ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">X</button></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                  <a href="<?php echo 'lineas_ver_cargar.php?fecha_siembra=' . $fecha_siembra . '&bloque=' . $bloque_linea . '&seccion=' . $seccion . '&ano=' . $ano . '&orden=' . $cosa->orden; ?>"><button class="btn btn-success" type="button">+</button></a>
                </td>

                </tr>





                <!--Fin formulario para lineas nuevas-->

              <?php } /*FIN DEL FOREACH DE LOS LINEAS MOSTRADAS*/ ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Los botones verdes me llevan a un formulario done ingreso el nuevo registro, por GET envio la info necesaria para que se me guarda en el grupo corrresocdinte y tambien envio la posicion del registro donde hice click al boton. Ahora el nuevo registro deberia estar justo debajo del registro de donde hice click.. No se si logro esplcarme. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no al final

Este codigo crear el registro. Como veran si es una entrada al final lo resolvi buscando el ultimo registro y su orden y arranco desde alli. Mi problema es cuando quieren agregar uno a la mitad y despues sumar uno a los siguientes para cuando haga el select aparezcan en el orden deseado.

```
'  if ($crear_linea) {

  $orden_crear = $_POST['orden_crear'];
  $fecha_siembra = $_POST['fecha_siembra'];

  $ano_crear =  $_POST['ano'];

  $bloque = $_POST['bloque_linea'];
  $seleccion = $_POST['seleccion'];
  $lineas_carac_seccion = $_POST['seccion_linea'];


  $lineas_carac_estaca = $_POST['lineas_carac_estaca'];





  $linea_num = $_POST['linea_num'];

  $lineas_carac_ao = $_POST['lineas_carac_ao'];
  $lineas_carac_rc = $_POST['lineas_carac_rc'];
  $lineas_carac_numsemilla = $_POST['lineas_carac_numsemilla'];  //
  $lineas_carac_germinacion = $_POST['lineas_carac_germinacion'];
  $lineas_carac_generacion = $_POST['lineas_carac_generacion'];
  $lineas_carac_observaciones = $_POST['lineas_carac_observaciones'];
  $lineas_carac_paf = $_POST['lineas_carac_paf'];

  //para poder tomar el utlimo orden de la linea y hacer consecutivo

  $query = "SELECT orden FROM lineas_carac WHERE bloque = '$bloque' AND ano = '$ano_crear' AND lineas_carac_seccion = '$lineas_carac_seccion'";
  $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $resultadojson = json_encode($resultado);
  $obj = json_decode($resultadojson);
  foreach ($obj as $cosa) {
    $orden = $cosa->orden;
  }
  if ($orden_crear != "") {
    $orden = $orden_crear;
  }
  //primero vamos a ver de que largo es le array para saber cuantas lineas se van a crear con el ciclo for


  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($lineas_carac_estaca); $i++) {

    $orden = $orden + 1;

    $lineas_carac_porcentaje_germinacion = ($lineas_carac_germinacion[$i] / $lineas_carac_numsemilla[$i]) * 100; //// CALCULAR EL PORCENTAJE

    $lineas_carac_i = $lineas_carac_germinacion[$i] * 100;




    $query = "INSERT INTO lineas_carac (lineas_carac_seleccion, bloque, lineas_carac_estaca, lineas_carac_ao, lineas_carac_rc, lineas_carac_numsemilla, lineas_carac_germinacion, lineas_carac_porcentaje_germinacion, lineas_carac_generacion, lineas_carac_observaciones, linea_num, lineas_carac_paf, lineas_carac_i, ano, lineas_carac_seccion, lineas_carac_fecha_siembra, orden) VALUE ('$seleccion[$i]', '$bloque', '$lineas_carac_estaca[$i]', '$lineas_carac_ao[$i]', '$lineas_carac_rc[$i]', '$lineas_carac_numsemilla[$i]', '$lineas_carac_germinacion[$i]', '$lineas_carac_porcentaje_germinacion', '$lineas_carac_generacion[$i]', '$lineas_carac_observaciones[$i]', '$linea_num[$i]', '$lineas_carac_paf[$i]', '$lineas_carac_i', '$ano_crear', '$lineas_carac_seccion', '$fecha_siembra', '$orden')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);


    $query = "INSERT INTO lineas_db (lineas_db_seleccion, bloque, ano, linea_num, lineas_db_seccion) VALUE ('$seleccion[$i]', '$bloque', '$ano_crear', '$linea_num[$i]', '$lineas_carac_seccion')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $query = "INSERT INTO lineas_lab_fruto (lineas_lab_fruto_seleccion, bloque, linea_num, ano, lineas_lab_fruto_seccion) VALUE ('$seleccion[$i]', '$bloque', '$linea_num[$i]', '$ano_crear', '$lineas_carac_seccion')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $query = "INSERT INTO lineas_lab_semilla (lineas_lab_semilla_seleccion, bloque, linea_num, ano, lineas_lab_semilla_seccion) VALUE ('$seleccion[$i]', '$bloque', '$linea_num[$i]', '$ano_crear', '$lineas_carac_seccion')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $query = "INSERT INTO lineas_repro (lineas_repro_seleccion, bloque, linea_num, ano, lineas_repro_seccion) VALUE ('$seleccion[$i]', '$bloque', '$linea_num[$i]', '$ano_crear', '$lineas_carac_seccion')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $query = "INSERT INTO lineas_veg (lineas_veg_seleccion, bloque, linea_num, ano, lineas_veg_seccion) VALUE ('$seleccion[$i]', '$bloque', '$linea_num[$i]', '$ano_crear', '$lineas_carac_seccion')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  }
}'
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar código (como texto) donde se vea cómo armas la tabla y cómo agregas productos.

Comment: Ese es el codigo que genera la tabla

Comment: En el enlace del botón verde ya estás incluyendo el orden, solo tienes que tomarlo en la página donde vas a agregar producto para ponerlo donde corresponde. Por favor edita nuevamente la pregunta para agregar el código con el que agregas productos.

Comment: mmm no aparece mi codigo nuevo

Comment: @Serafy: Diria que sí. Vete arriba del todo y pulsa sobre el texto que dice que la pregunta se ha editado para recargarla, o bien recarga la pagina

Comment: Ahora logre actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: En el enlace envías orden donde se debe agregar el producto, sin embargo, tienes una consulta para obtener orden y leyendo todos los productos, podrías leer solo el último con `ORDER BY orden DESC LIMIT 1`. Necesitas algunas validaciones, de lo contrario, siempre se agregará al final.

Comment: thk. Y bueno justamente logro eso. leer el ultimo: Implementare tu consejo. Pero ahora como inserto en cualquier posicion para cuando haga el select * from tabla order by orden aparecezca donde quiero y no al final